Flutter: My keeps checking for supabase for images and text and not using cached images
I have an flutter app I am building. It gets it images and text from supabase. The app is supposed to open once and store the images in cache using the cached_network_image package and only get an updated image once one is loaded on supabase. The problem is that when I close the app and reopen it, it goes to supabase and gets the image. This is quite expensive in that the app is always doing a call to superbase when it startsup. What am I doing wrong?
  Future<String> fetchImageUrl() async {
    final response = await Supabase.instance.client
        .from('04_text_tile') // Replace with your table name
        .select(
            'front_image') // Replace with the column name that holds the image URL
        .single();

    if (response != null) {
      return response['front_image']; // Return the URL from the response
    }
    return ''; // Fallback URL if needed
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cached Network Image'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: fetchImageUrl(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Icon(Icons.error);
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: snapshot.data!,
                placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              );
            } else {
              return Text('No image found');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
   

